# Getting error: "o.map is not a function" when using google maps distance matrix api in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using the Google Maps API Node Client and calling the `distancematrix` function, but I'm getting an error that says `o.map is not a function`.

```
const {Client} = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js")
const client = new Client

client.distancematrix({
    params: {
        origins: '40,40',
        destinations: '40,41',
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
    }
})
.then((r) => {
    console.log(r.data.rows)
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

I tried looking at the Google Maps services code. I found `o.map` at line 174 at [this link](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/master/src/distance.ts#L174).

Comment: Surely the clue is in the plural naming? And you can see in the link where arrays were expected.

Comment: The documentation explains the types of inputs expected: arrays, strings, etc. i have tried them all.

Comment: You _haven't_ tried arrays because [that's what's expected](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/0526092e22ba4078384cd7f4d31b421328222556/src/distance.ts#L36-L70) and they do have a map method so you wouldn't get that error. Your IDE should be able to tell you this is wrong based on the types, you could use TypeScript to make that an earlier error.

Comment: I have been trying to understand the comments in the API source code that seem to suggest strings will work. I am also new to javascript so I would appreciate some more patience with your comments.

Comment: You mean [like this one](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/0526092e22ba4078384cd7f4d31b421328222556/src/distance.ts#L48)? That's how it would look _in a URL_, in a query parameter, not in JS. You need to look at the _types_ and the _error message_, both of which tell you you're missing an array somewhere. Or put a breakpoint in, debug and convince yourself that when `o = '40,40'`, `o.map` won't fly.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So there is no way to somehow use place id in lieu of the latlng array?

Comment: It's an array _of locations_ in various forms (as linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77810742/getting-error-o-map-is-not-a-function-when-using-google-maps-distance-matrix?noredirect=1#comment137174586_77810770) and despite the answer you've accepted incorrectly suggesting otherwise), so it's feasible the array could contain place ID strings. If not there may be a way to get a `LatLng` _from_ a place ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on this [given](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/master/src/distance.ts#L174) Google Maps service code, you have to pass the **origins & destinations** as an **array** of [lat, lang] values. As you are passing it as a `string` and `string` doesn't have the function call `map()`, it is throwing an error as **o.map is not a function**. Try the below code and check

```
client.distancematrix({
    params: {
        origins: [40, 40],
        destinations: [40, 41],
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
    }
})
.then((r) => {
    console.log(r.data.rows)
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
origins: '40,40',
        destinations: '40,41'
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! Follow-up question: how would it look if i wanted to use place ids?

Comment: It's an array _of [`LatLng`](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/0526092e22ba4078384cd7f4d31b421328222556/src/common.ts#L574-L585)_, not numbers.

Comment: Can you come up with some more context? Do you want to give place-id over latitude & longitude? Does it support the same? But I feel, it only supports the lat & long value here as origin & destination.

Comment: The API documentation states in the comments that it takes place-id as well as latitude & longitude. However, I don't know how to configure the formatting. I tried origins=place_id but i get errors

Comment: Can you please share that documentation here?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/master/src/distance.ts#L38) at line 38, it states how we can use place_id for origins and destinations

Comment: Then you have to apply the prefix `place_id:` always and this place_id will come from GeoCoding API. Example: `origins='place_id:ChIJ3S-JXmauEmsRUcIaWtf4MzE'`

Comment: But for **Lat Long**, you always have to use an array of [Lat, Long] to origins & destinations.

Answer (score 1):

The distancematrix function expects an array of origins and destinations, but in your code, you are passing a string for both. Instead, you should provide arrays of coordinates for origins and destinations.

```
    const { Client } = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js");
const client = new Client();

client.distancematrix({
  params: {
    origins: ['40,40'], // Pass an array of origins
    destinations: ['40,41'], // Pass an array of destinations
    key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.rows);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Make sure to pass arrays for origins and destinations, even if you have only one origin and one destination.

If the issue persists, you may also want to check the version of the @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js package you are using and update it to the latest version to ensure that you have the latest bug fixes.